# Computer hangs during POST only when restarted or when computer is warm

Tags: boot, bios, cooling, post

I have a problem booting my computer when it's been restarted or recently turned off (and still warm)

If i boot my computer when cold, it boots fine, I can use Windows and run it as normal but if I need to do a restart due to an update or turn if back on after a few minutes of being shut down, the computer starts, goes through POST and gets stuck after detecting the hard drives. I can't even get into BIOS at that point.  It's fine again if I give it half hour to cool down.

I've replaced the heatsink and cooler from a stock cooler, and the CPU in POST says it's running at 28°C. I even stripped the computer down taking everything out and giving it a good vacuuming to make sure there's no dust causing it but still same thing happens.

I've tried clearing the CMOS by taking the battery out and moving the CMOS clear jumper but still same problem occurs.

I did initially think it was overheating but I don't see that as a problem now because there is no dust anymore.

Anyone got any suggestions on what to try?

Comment: how new/old is this system? What sort of video card?

Comment: It's about 5 years old. Sapphire 690V Chipset PE-AM2RS690V2. Can't remember the video card off hand. I'm sure it's an ATI Radeon HD of some description